# add class to the match element id from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var active_menu = "menu2";

         //here do like, add .active to the #menu2 element.
    });
</script>


<ul>
    <li id="menu1"><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu2"><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu3"><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now what I want is to add a class name named "active" to the match element id name within the active_menu variable. How to do that? I know I can use if and else statement or switch to achieve that but it will look awfully long way code implementation.

PS: to sharpen the details above, basically what I'm trying to do is add a class to the element which has an id match to the variable active_menu.

any help, suggestions, recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you familiarise yourself with the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) as this really is very simple to research and implement.

Comment: Are you trying to implement tabs ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can do this

```
$('#' + active_menu).addClass('active');
```

Comment: works like charm. theres something missing anyway. the id so make it complete. I just added #. $('#' + active_menu).addClass('active');

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var active_menu = "menu2";
    $('#'+active_menu).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xojbgon9/)

```
$(function(){
    var active_menu = "menu2";
    $('#'+active_menu).addClass('active');
    $('#'+active_menu).find('a').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#' + active_menu).addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var active_menu = "menu2";
        $('#'+active_menu ).addClass('active');
         //here do like, add .active to the #menu2 element.
    });
```